# Developing user interface to replace windows UI

Tags: .net, user-interface, vb6, customization

I would like to develop an application similar to [Thinix touch](http://www.thinix.com/product.asp?p=8FDF2852-CE87-4FEB-A830-542F609F5959)

What tools would I need? Would visual basic 6 or Visual C++ be sufficient? I do know that some functions can be done using shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For touch based windows programming I highly recommend WPF. 

**Touch**
Heres a short sample of why : http://www.wpftutorial.net/Multitouch2.html 

Another cool sample (in silverlight) : http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=1136

Heres a microsoft provided walkthrough : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx

PS: all standard controls offer touch out of the box (just like any windows application in any windows language) 

**Rich User Interface composition**

 WPF was designed for enabling next generation great interfaces. Check out the samples : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928128/wpf-any-cool-ui-ideas-i-can-look-at

Comment: looks complex.. haha.. I will check it out.
Thanks a lot. Is WPF will work on NOT touch based windows OS?
Will it hide the mouse cursor?

Comment: You can hide the mouse cursor by setting the Top windows Cursor property to null. Yes it will work on not touch based windows OS. It will work on windows XP and above.

Comment: Just found out thinix touch is application that can replace window shell. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell_replacement

Comment: Then can I said WPF is like HTML & C# is like PHP, WPF is use to create UI, and C# is use to create functions.

Comment: Actually xaml is like HTML and c# is like php+JavaScript would be more appropriate. WPF is a GUI framework accessible from both xaml and c# but generally most of the presentation work is in xaml. Hope it's clear.